# Initially fold certain(code) blocks in phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I know phpstorm supports certain PHPDOC annotations to perform certain parser operations for example for the code inspection to not inspect certain areas.

Now I wonder is there such an annotation (correct word even?) to fold certain blocks of code (or classes/methods/functions even) to always initially fold that block upon loading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom code folding regions](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/new-in-4-0-custom-code-folding-regions/) were introduced in PhpStorm 4.0.

Comment: According to one of the comments the folded state should be kept remembered by the IDE, that quite answers my question. Guess I'll just have to first-time-fold them :-) Thanks.